# How can I place a var in a mailto post

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I would like to input an email addy via a form then place that addy in the cc area of a mailto post. Is this possible &/or safe?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<form action="mailto:address@example.com">
    <input name="cc">
</form>
```